# How To Use C++ CGI Script?

Tags: c++, html, cgi

I am currently enrolled in a web applications class at my college and we are learning about cgi scripts. I am having a hard time learning how to implement my CGI script. When I click on my link a window pops up asking me to download my helloworld.cgi file instead of just redirecting.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="/user/local/apache2/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi">click me</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**C++:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Content-type: text/html" << endl;
    cout << "<html>" << endl;
    cout << "   <body>" << endl;
    cout << "       Hello World!" << endl;
    cout << "   </body>" << endl;
    cout << "</html>" << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

The CGI script is stored at `/user/local/apache2/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi`

Comment: Just to confirm, you are running this CGI on a web server and not off the local file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/user/local/apache2/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi` is the physical path of the file on your hard disk. To run the script through Apache, you need to specify the path relative to your server's document root, for eg. `http://localhost/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi`.

Answer (score 15):

You need to compile the C++ file, and call the result helloworld.cgi.  C++ is not a scripting language -- you can't just deploy it to your server.

On a typical *nix system, name the C++ file helloworld.cpp

```
 gcc -o helloworld.cgi helloworld.cpp
```

Then put that file in your cgi-bin

Edit: you need two endl's after the last header item

```
  cout << "Content-type: text/html" << endl << endl;
```

Comment: `endl` isn't necessarily enough, HTTP mandates CR-LF as the EOL, `endl` is platform specific.

Comment: I was referring the apache2 cgi doc and no where it's mentioned to compile it and name it `.cgi`. Your answer helped me run a simple c++ script as a cgi script

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, and this solution worked for me : 
First run this commands on terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then copy helloworld.cgi to /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

```
sudo cp helloworld.cgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
```

And finally change href link to:

```
  <a href="/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to configure Apache to recognise a `cgi-bin` properly...

Have a read of this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/cgi.html

In Apache config `ScriptAlias` is probably what you want.

(I'm assuming you've compiled the binary to helloworld.cgi)