# Using System() with C in CGI

Tags: c, cgi

I got an assignment that consists of developing a web server on a Raspberry Pi so that I can administrate users (think add, delete, permissions, but from the server)l

I have pretty much everything (LAMP, HTML form that calls a .cgi script written in C), but I tried using `System()` to make my job easier, but it doesn't work!

I want to use `system(add user)` from the CGI script, but I think it's restricted.

My question is, how do I use `System (written in C)` in a CGI script, or, what permissions to add and how??

Note: Security breaches don't matter much because it's only for a presentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
system( "some command" );
```

for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   char command[50];

// In Unix:
   strcpy( command, "cp file.txt h.txt" );
   system(command);

// In Windows:
   strcpy( command, "copy file.txt h.txt" );
   system(command);


   return(0);
}
```

[How To Use C++ CGI Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824273/how-to-use-c-cgi-script)